# The function doesn't increment the given variable

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

When the user clicks the button, it will verify if any radio button was checked(`checkChoices()`) and if so, it will compare the value of the checked radio button with the `correctAnswer`.

The problem is with the `keepScore()` function because the `score` remains 0 for any answer.

```
var score = 0;
var checkChoices = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
        if (choices[i].checked) {
            var value = choices[i].value;
            choices[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
    return value;
};

//the keepScore function doesn't increment
var keepScore = function(){
    if(checkChoices() == allQuestions[y].correctAnswer) {
        score++;
    }
};

var behavior = function(){
    if(y<allQuestions.length-1 && checkChoices()) {
        keepScore();
        y++;
    }
};

nextBtn.onclick = function(){
    behavior();
};
```

Comment: Are you sure that you even call `keepScore()` function? On your button you should use `type="button"`.

Comment: Did you read the code? I invoked it in the `behavior()` function. Yep, I used `type='button'` but it will not make a difference because is not within a form.

Comment: What is `y` in `behavior`?

Comment: `y` is a global variable with the value of 0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the var value at the beginning of the function.
Your function will always return undefined otherwise because the var needs to be within the scope of the return statement at least.

Comment: Why is that? The `score` variable is global so it's not a problem to access it within a function.

Comment: The variable named "value".

Comment: ` var checkChoices = function(){ var value ; // here to declare   for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) { if (choices[i].checked) { value = choices[i].value; choices[i].checked = false; } } return value; };`

Comment: Oh, my fault. In JS variables can be function scoped and not block level scoped. Confuses me always ;-)